# Can Sharepoint logon be used to control dynamic queries

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We are developing a Sharepoint web site for customers to view data imported from Nav 2015.

We could develop unique page for each client showing data in excel format, but this would require high maintenance.

Is there a method of issuing logins that can be used to control dynamic queries limiting data view to that client's information?

Comment: Questions: Where the imported data is stored? Is in stored in SharePoint list, Excel file, or is it some external database? What to you mean in excel format? Is it grid, table, or do you want to show in Excel Services WebPart? What SharePoint version is it?

Comment: Hi, the data will be linked to a NAV 2015 sales stats table. I believe that the NAV 2015 can be exposed in a Sharepoint list. I write in VBA I am out of my depth in Sharepoint but learning. We would like to use an excel services web part to graph the results. Currently the Sharepoint is on an SBS 2011 server with SQL on a separate server  but we may upgrade SP if required.

Answer (score 0):

According to your information, that your data is in SQL database, scenario which could be possible:

1. Create a Business Connectivity Services (BCS) entity for your data from your NAV database. BCS allows you to access remote data from other sources to SharePoint. Here is step-by-step example how to implement this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/02/10/173-a-step-by-step-guide-in-designing-bcs-entities-by-using-a-sql-stored-procedure.aspx
2. Create a External List based on your BCS entity. Look at the first article the same article
3. Use filtering technique filter your external data showed in External List as described in this article: https://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/

> **Note** You could get much more flexibility for filtering, searching and displaying your data using SharePoint Search. But note, that SBS ships with SharePoint Foundation, which does not have Search build-in. On the other hand you can deploy [Search Server 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18914) in your farm and check if you can index BCS entities. Here is MSDN nice quidance [how to work with Search and External data in BCS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg512148(v=office.14).aspx). In SharePoint 2013 search there is a token {User:Name} to search by username, but I in SharePoint 2010 you have to check.

Comment: Hi many thanks for your answer very helpful. The filter that we would want to automatically apply is NAV bill to account and ship to account. These cannot be a user selection. I think we will have to create a logon table that contains the filter fields. Tim